# HTTP Redirect based on Full Request URI

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, uri

Looking to take the request URI string and then direct it into a folder named the exact same. So if the file is 111111111.cfg.

I would like it to redirect into `http://myserver.test.com/111111111/`

```
<!-- language: none -->

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myserver.test.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{12})/(.*)  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L]
```

Comment: Do you always want to take first 12 characters?

Comment: i assume just split of the extension?

Comment: Doesn't `http://myserver.test.com/111111111/` give 404 to you?